# Catch exception without throwing type

Tags: c#, exception, xunit

I am new to xUnit and I am trying to increase my test coverage. I have a class structure that looks like so:

```
public class Class1 
{
   public override void Method1() 
   {
      try 
      {
         // some code logic
      } 
      catch (CoreException ex)
      {
         BmpException lex = new BmpException();
         throw lex;
      }
      catch (CodedException ex)
      {
         BmpException lex = new BmpException();
         throw lex;
      }
   }
}
```

And my xUnit Testing method looks like so:

```
[Fact]
public void TestMethod()
{
   Class1 SomeClass = new Class1();

   // Works but doesn't affect code coverage ?
   Assert.Throws<BmpException>(() => SomeClass.Method1());

   // Test failed - Expected: CodedException Actual: BmpException
   // Assert.Throws<CodedException>(() => SomeClass.Method1());

   // Test failed - Expected: CoreException Actual: BmpException
   // Assert.Throws<CoreException>(() => SomeClass.Method1());
}
```

So the issue I am facing here is I need to cover the testing for the CoreException and the CodedException blocks. Since Assert.Throws<> catches the expression AND asserts the type, I am unable to find a workaround to complete my test coverage.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you,

Comment: Your code wouldn't compile, because you are using the same `ex` name for exception, declared in the same scope

Comment: You're right I was just writing from memory, I just edited my code. My question remains the same though, thanks

Comment: `throw ex` resets the stack trace, it isn't such a good idea. You are throwing `BmpException` at every catch block, why do you expect its work?

Comment: So do you have a solution or work around to my issue? Or are you just commenting?

Comment: Does your exception class accepts InnerException as constructor Argument? If not then it should. Pass the original exception in your custom exception `BmpException lex = new BmpException(ex);` this will preserve the stack trace in InnerException. This is the standard way to wrap exception to add additional information and keeping the original exception as well. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a class structure that looks like so:

Its typically very bad practice to simply throw a different exception because you lose all relevant information.  At the **very least** you should [wrap the exception](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/66925/is-wrapping-exceptions-good-practice).

Because you have **not** included all relevant code

```
// some code logic
```

It's impossible to give you an programmatic answer.  The only real answer one can give based on the lack of information is that your tests need to cause the *some code logic* to throw each of the types of exceptions (`CoreException` and `CodedException`) in order to increase your code coverage.

> // Test failed - Expected: CodedException Actual: BmpException
>
> // Assert.Throws(() => SomeClass.Method1());

You can NEVER assert the type as `CoreException` nor `CodedException` because they are being [Swallowed or Error Hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_hiding).  Those exceptions are lost inside the method call for all time.

> Since Assert.Throws<> catches the expression AND asserts the type, I am unable to find a workaround

You have to catch the type that is being thrown:

```
var ex = Assert.Throws<BmpException>(() => SomeClass.Method1());
```

You don't care how why it's really that type of exception as long as you can provide a way for the logic to throw that type via that specific logically programmed route.

For example:

```cs
public void AnyBodyWantAPeanut(int i)
{
  try 
  {
    if (i == 1) 
      throw new InvalidOperationException("You keep using that word");
    if (i == 2) 
      throw new ArgumentException("I don't think it means");
    throw new ArithmeticException ("What you think it means");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Throw Exception("No more rhymes now I mean it!");
  }
}
```

This has a cyclomatic complexity of 3, as there are three possible routes, even though there is only one outcome.  To have 100% code coverage with this code the following tests would have to tested by making sure the logic supports the outcome:

```
public class Class1_Tests
{
  public AnyBodyWantAPeanut_WithValue1_ReturnsException
  {
    //Assign
    var a = new Class1();
    //Act
    var method = () => a.AnyBodyWantAPeanut(1);
    //Assert
    Assert.Throws<Exception>(method);
  }
  
  public AnyBodyWantAPeanut_WithValue2_ReturnsException
  {
    //Assign
    var a = new Class1();
    //Act
    var method = () => a.AnyBodyWantAPeanut(2);
    //Assert
    Assert.Throws<Exception>(method);
  }

  public AnyBodyWantAPeanut_WithValue1_ReturnsException
  {
    //Assign
    var a = new Class1();
    //Act
    var method = () => a.AnyBodyWantAPeanut(0);
    //Assert
    Assert.Throws<Exception>(method);
  }
}
```

Comment: It's interesting to think about the *atypical* cases where it *is* the right thing to do, to throw away the original exception and propagate a non-wrapping exception back to the caller. My personal favourite example: before the first beta version of .NET shipped, it was possible to catch a security violation exception that *told your code the name of the file whose name your code was not allowed to know* because that information was in the exception. There are numerous such situations to consider when designing exceptions for secure code.

Comment: @EricLippert sure, I believe there are always times when there are exceptions to a rule (for example: always wrap an exception). Unless someone has explicitly stated why they aren't following the rule, I feel like it's my responsibility ethically to at least make them aware of the issue.  I find more often than not, OP aren't aware of the issues and my comments could indirectly improve software.

Comment: Exactly; my comment was not intended as a critique but rather as a way to think about the problem. We often can come to understand the typical case better by carefully examining the atypical cases.

Comment: I took as a critique in the positive direction, then just explained it so other's who might read my comment might start doing the same as well :)

Comment: That is exactly why, I just started working at a top 500 fortune company and 90% of all their exceptions (at least on the project I'm on) are custom exceptions for security reasons... Its making testing annoying. But your answer did help me complete my test case, so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the raised exception like this:

```
 var ex = Assert.Throws<BmpException>(() => SomeClass.Method1());

 Assert.Equal("test message", ex.Message);
```

Assuming that `BmpException` is inherited from `System.Exception` class. To preserve the original you should pass the original exception in your custom exception `BmpException lex = new BmpException(ex);` this will preserve the stack trace in InnerException. This is the standard way to wrap exception to add additional information and keeping the original exception as well. This way you will be able to assert on InnerException.

```
Assert.Equal(typeof(CoreException), ex.InnerException.GetType());
//Add as many assertion as you like here.
```